# numpy indexing using 'None' for pairwise operations

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting, numpy-ndarray

If I had two numpy arrays that looked like this

```
a = np.array([1, 2])
b = np.array([3, 4])
```

and I wanted to add all pairwise combinations, I could easily do

```
c = a + b[:, None]
c
array([[4, 5],
       [5, 6]])
```

to get the result of **1+3**, **2+3** and **1+4**, **2+4**.

Why does this work? What is 'None' doing? I can print out

```
b[:, None]
[[3]
 [4]]
```

But I'm not sure why that tells numpy to do pairwise combos. I'm also curious about if it's efficiently implemented under the hood compared to, say, itertools.combinations.

Comment: You're broadcasting

Comment: Also is your question why `b[:, None]` returns that array with shape `(2,1)`, or why adding a `(2,)` shape array and a `(2, 1)` shape array produce that result

Comment: both, i guess :)

Comment: Look at `b.shape` and `b[:, None].shape`.

Comment: `b[:, None]` has the same behavior as `b[:, np.newaxis]`, it adds an additional dimension to your array, and the addition behavior just has to do with how numpy handles broadcasting.  [This](http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/EricsBroadcastingDoc) is a helpful article to understand this concept better

Comment: thanks! the article is real helpful. post it as an answer if you'd like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the first part of your question, `b[:, None]` is a special type of slicing that has identical  behavior to `b[:, np.newaxis]`, in that it adds an axis of length 1 to your array.

```
>>> b.shape
(2,)
>>> b[:, None].shape
(2, 1)
```

This behavior is documented in the [**`numpy`** docs <sup>[1]</sup>](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis), emphasis mine:

> The `newaxis` object can be used in all slicing operations to create an axis of length one. **`newaxis` is an alias for `None`, and `None` can be used in place of this with the same result.**

So now we have two arrays:

```
array([1, 2]) + array([[3],
                       [4]])
```

Summing these two arrays results in:

```
array([[4, 5],
       [5, 6]])
```

The "magic" behind this is [**`numpy`** broadcasting<sup>[2]</sup>](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html).  [This article <sup>[3]</sup>](http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/EricsBroadcastingDoc) is an excellent resource for beginning to understand the topic.

---

The main takeaways from the article are as follows:

**`numpy`** operations are usually done element-by-element which requires two arrays to have exactly the same shape.  However, this constraint is relaxed if both arrays have the same trailing axis, ***or if one of the trailing axes is equal to one*** (which is the behavior being exhibited in your case).

In your case, broadcasting occurs, so the operation is equivalent to summing the following 2x2 arrays:

```
array([[1, 2],    +  array([[3, 3],
       [1, 2]])            [4, 4]])
```

Which, since numpy operations are done element-by-element, will produce the desired output of:

```
array([[4, 5],
       [5, 6]])
```

---

<sub><sup>[1]</sup>https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis</sub>

<sub><sup>[2]</sup>https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html</sub>

<sub><sup>[3]</sup>http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/EricsBroadcastingDoc</sub>

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is adding a new axis: the "column"-axis. `b` didn't have that before, so now it's a column vector and would be added column wise; it will essentially act as if it was repeated in the columns, and `a` repeated in the rows:

```
a+b[:, None] = [1,2] + [[3], = [[1,2], + [[3],[3],
                        [4]]    [1,2]]    [4],[4]]
```

And here is how/why:

First things first: `numpy` does elementwise addition and multiplication by default. That means if `a=np.array([1,2])` then `a+2=np.array([1+2,2+2])=np.array([3,5])`.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1, 2],
              [3, 4]])
B = np.array([[1,1],
              [0,0]])
```

Here `A+B` would be element wise and we would get

```
A+B = [[1+1,2+1], = [[2,3],
       [3+0,4+0]] =  [3,4]]
```

If we transpose the matrix `B` (using `B.T`)

now `B.T` would have the value

```
B.T= np.array([[1,0],
               [1,0]])
```

And if we do it elementwise this time we'd get:

```
A+B.T=[[1, 2]  + [[1,0]  =  [[2,2],
       [3, 4]]    [1,0]]     [4,4]]
```

Another thing to notice is that (`B` *not* transposed)

```
a = np.array([1,2])
B+a = [[1,2], + [[2, 3],
       [1,2]]    [1, 2]]
```

And it's also elementwise, but on both rows! That is `a` was practically "repeated"  to have two rows, and added elementwise to `B`.

Further, [Numpy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html) says that `None`, in slicing, is a different way of writing `np.newaxis`.  In your case, what the `None` option in slicing does is basically transposing the `b`-vector before addition!

The exact same result could have been obtained by

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2])
b = np.array([3, 4])

c=a+b.reshape(2,1)
d=a+b.reshape(-1,1)
e=a+b[:, np.newaxis]
```

Here `c`, `d` and `e` have the same values!